# Change image size via parent div

Tags: html, image-size

I tried to do so but it didn't change the size:

```
<div style="height:42px;width:42px">
   <img src="http://someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

What will re-size it (I can't edit/access the img element itself)?

Comment: set one dimension. the other dimension will resize to scale evenly. <img style="height:42px;" src="http://someimage.jpg">

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by "I have no access to image" But if you have access to parent div you can do the following:

Firs give id or class to your div:

```
<div class="parent">
   <img src="http://someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Than add this to your css:

```
.parent {
   width: 42px; /* I took the width from your post and placed it in css */
   height: 42px;
}

/* This will style any <img> element in .parent div */
.parent img {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Which was exactly what Sarfraz said :)

Comment: @Mattis Oh true, sorry I didn't read the comments, same stuff indeed ))

Comment: A solid solution!  **Note:** You don't _have_ set the height.  I left that out in my declaration and let the height be automatic while the width conforms to that of its parent.

Answer (score 10):

Apply `100%` width and height to your image:

```
<div style="height:42px;width:42px">
  <img src="http://someimage.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100%">
</div>
```

This way it will same size of its parent.

Comment: @agam360: Then you will have to use JS, updating answer.

Comment: @Sarfraz, No other way? (I won't use js also :(  )  But I can user php functions.

Comment: @agam360: Do you have access to parent div ? In that case, css can be used.

Comment: @agam360: If you have access to parent div, you can use this css then: `#parentDiv img { height: 100%; width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 1):

Actually using 100% will not make the image bigger if the image is smaller than the div size you specified. You need to set one of the dimensions, height or width in order to have all images fill the space. In my experience it's better to have the height set so each row is the same size, then all items wrap to next line properly. This will produce an output similar to fotolia.com  (stock image website)

with css:

```
parent {
   width: 42px; /* I took the width from your post and placed it in css */
   height: 42px;
}

/* This will style any <img> element in .parent div */
.parent img {
   height: 42px;
}
```

without:

```
<div style="height:42px;width:42px">
    <img style="height:42px" src="http://someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this way:

```
<div class="card-logo">
    <img height="100%" width="100%" src="http://someimage.jpg">
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.card-logo {
    width: 20%;
}
```

I prefer this way, as if I need to upscale - I can use 150% as well

Answer (score 0):

Yours:

```
  <div style="height:42px;width:42px">
  <img src="http://someimage.jpg">
```

Is it okay to use this code?

```
  <div class= "box">
  <img src= "http://someimage.jpg" class= "img">
  </div>

  <style type="text/css">
  .box{width: 42; height: 42;}
  .img{width: 20; height:20;}
  </style>
```

Just trying, though late. :3
For someone else reading this, letme know if the way i wrote the code were not good. im new in this kind of language. and i still want to learn more.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Using CSS and inline styles are equivalent

Comment: Try to answer questions with answers, not further questions. Welcome to the site! :)