# Make a p have the same width/height as an image that is placed in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, picturefill

I am trying to make a p always have the same width and height as an image that is placed next to it.

I set specific dimensions to both of the divs containing those elements, and then set the img width and height to 100% (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556514/change-image-size-via-parent-div)). Unfortunately that led to images getting distorted even if I used the dimensions of the actual images being provided. Forgot to mention that I use Picturefill by the way, perhaps it has something to do with that..

I should mention that it is possible to somewhat control the amount of distortion, by adjusting the values in the *sizes* attribute of the picturefill HTML. However it turned out that I would have to add thousands of different values to that attribute to actually make it work this way. It just didn't really feel like the correct approach to something like this.

**HTML**

```
<div> 
  <img 
     sizes="(min-width: ...px) ...vw, (min-width: ...px) ...vw etc"
     srcset="/images/img1.jpg 280w,
             /images/img2.jpg 350w"
     alt="...">
</div>

<div> 
 <p> ... </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: How about using jquery `width = $('img').css('width'); heigth = $('img').css('height')` and then just set the sizes of either the `<p>` tag or the `<div>` to those two values

Comment: @FMashiro I did it and it certainly works much better this way. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image `width` to `100%` and `height` to `auto`. That way, the image will preserve its aspect ratio while still being resized.

Comment: Thank you, this certainly solves the distortion part. I hope there is also a solution to the main problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve then? `width: auto; height: auto;`?

Comment: I am trying to make a div that is a sibling of the parent div of the img to always have the same dimensions as the img itself. Perhaps I should mention that the div the img is placed in, doesn't have any other children. So I'm looking for a way to force the two divs to always have the same dimensions. Thank you for your time by the way.