# Css image just fit with certain width

Tags: html, css

i want to **fit image with parent** div (image-container) with **corect ratio**

```css
.image-container{

height: 195px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 482px;
    width: 482px;
    
    }
    
    img{
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: contain;
overflow:hidden
    }
    
    .gray-layer{
    width: 482px;
    height: 195px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://javadeveloperzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/JAVA-PARSE-LARGE-JSON-FILE-GSON-EXAMPLE-1024x488.png">
<div class="gray-layer">
</div>
</div>
```

my above code doesn't fit the image. please help me

Comment: Please clarify: do you want the `.image-container` to adapt its size according to the image dimensions, or do you want to have the image be scaled so that it fully fills out the div (which, when conserving aspect ratio, can mean that there will be parts of the image cut off)?

Comment: Or maybe you want the image to take on the parent's width, possibly leaving empty space in the vertical direction? If so, do you want the image to be aligned at the top, center or bottom of the container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change image size via parent DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556514/change-image-size-via-parent-div)

Comment: I need fit just by width and overflow of the image just hidden but width:100% just fit the height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use `overflow: hidden` on the parent `div` in order to have the rounded corner work for the contained `img` without having to specify them again.

Then, if you want the `img` to always fill out the entirety of the parent `div`, then you should set `width` and `height` to `100%` and use `object-fit: cover`:

```css
.image-container {
  width: 482px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://javadeveloperzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/JAVA-PARSE-LARGE-JSON-FILE-GSON-EXAMPLE-1024x488.png">
</div>
```

If you, however, want the image to just take on the parent's width (possibly growing out or leaving space at the bottom), then setting `width` to `100%` should do the trick:

```css
.image-container {
  width: 482px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://javadeveloperzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/JAVA-PARSE-LARGE-JSON-FILE-GSON-EXAMPLE-1024x488.png">
</div>
```

Note that I've omitted the `.gray-layer` for brevity and added a border to `image-container` to better see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add missing ending div and give height/width to 100% to get it working.

```css
.image-container {
  height: 195px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 482px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.gray-layer {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://javadeveloperzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/JAVA-PARSE-LARGE-JSON-FILE-GSON-EXAMPLE-1024x488.png">
  <div class="gray-layer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not preserve the image's aspect ratio unless the parent div's size is a perfect ratio fit. I believe you can even see the image being somewhat stretched here.

Comment: is there a solution for fit just by width and overflow of the height image just hidden?